# What is the smallest period of $f(x)=3\sin^2\pi x+2x-\lfloor2x\rfloor$?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, periodic-functions

> The function $f(x)=3\sin^2\pi x+2x-\lfloor2x\rfloor$ is defined in
> real numbers. What is the smallest period of the function?
>
> $1)1\qquad\qquad2)2\qquad\qquad3)\pi\qquad\qquad4)2\pi$

Period of $2x-\lfloor 2x\rfloor$ is $\frac12$ and I think period of $\sin^2\pi x=\cfrac{1-\cos(2\pi x)}{2}$ is $\dfrac{2\pi}{2\pi}=1$.

Hence period of $f(x)$ is $1$. Am I right?

Comment: The period should only be affected by the π, so the period may be a natural number. Also [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fh5cjvr5y3) it. The period of the floor function is also natural as it is not based in the circle.

Comment: You can check them one by one.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Do you mean starting from the least number (called $c$) in options and comparing $f(x)$ and $f(x+c)$ ?

Comment: @Soheil Yes, since you have only four possibilities.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Good idea! thanks!

Comment: But I think what you have done is pretty quick too and it is correct.

Comment: Also you did not have to rewrite $\sin^2(\pi x)$ in a different form. We know period of $\sin (\pi x)$ is $2$ and so the period of $\sin^2(\pi x)$ will be $1$.

Comment: Both $t\mapsto \sin^2\pi t$ and $t\mapsto \{t\}:=x-\lfloor t\rfloor$ have minimal period $1$.  The minimal period in your problem is $1$.